# duda con get php en formulario php

Tags: php, formularios, get

tengo un formulario en el que uso el id para agregarselo a la url en una nueva pagina , luego del formulario

```html
<h1 align="center">mi nuevo registro</h1>
<form action="registro.php">
<input name="usuario" type="text" placeholder="usuario" />
<br>
<input name="cedula" type="text" placeholder="cedula" /> 
<br>
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

mi codigo php ingresa los datos , al momento de ingresarlos mando el al url la variable usuario asi

```
<?php
header("Location: registro.php?$usuario");
?>
```

el problema es que necesito tomar ese dato $usuario para un nuevo formulario en otra pagina para pasarlo a otra pagina ,
¿como puedo obtener ese dato ?

Comment: puedes almacenarlos en una cookies o enviar los datos por GET nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Te falta ponerle nombre al parámetro.

```
header("Location: registro.php?user=$usuario")
```

Supongo que $usuario lo rellenas en otra parte

Comment: deberias agregar como obtener al usuario probablemente se sienta un poco perdido

Answer (score 1):

Como te dijeron arriba, al parámetro que envías lo tienes que enviar con un nombre:

```
header("Location: registro.php?user=$usuario")
```

Y para poder usarlo dentro del archivo registro.php lo haces con $_GET[], por ejemplo:

```
echo $_GET['user'];
```

Con eso lo muestras.

Aunque no es la mejor opción para enviar datos de un formulario, para eso está el método POST.

Comment: hola victor, podrias decirme un link para ver como hacerlo por post? 
gracias, ya lo pruebo